# Mapping complex JSON to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

**Background**
I have a complex nested JSON object, which I am trying to unpack into a pandas `df` in a very specific way.

**JSON Object**
this is an extract, containing randomized data of the JSON object, which shows examples of the hierarchy (inc. children) for 1x family (i.e. 'Falconer Family'), however there is 100s of them in total and this extract just has 1x family, however the full JSON object has multiple -

```
{
    "meta": {
        "columns": [{
                "key": "value",
                "display_name": "Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)",
                "output_type": "Number",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "time_weighted_return",
                "display_name": "Current Quarter TWR (USD)",
                "output_type": "Percent",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "time_weighted_return_2",
                "display_name": "YTD TWR (USD)",
                "output_type": "Percent",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "key": "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328",
                "display_name": "TWR Audit Note",
                "output_type": "Word"
            }
        ],
        "groupings": [{
                "key": "_custom_name_747205",
                "display_name": "* Reporting Client Name"
            },
            {
                "key": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                "display_name": "NEW Entity Group"
            },
            {
                "key": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                "display_name": "* Level 2"
            },
            {
                "key": "legal_entity",
                "display_name": "Legal Entity"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "portfolio_views",
        "attributes": {
            "total": {
                "name": "Total",
                "columns": {
                    "time_weighted_return": -0.046732301295604683,
                    "time_weighted_return_2": -0.046732301295604683,
                    "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                    "value": 23132492.905107163
                },
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Falconer Family",
                    "grouping": "_custom_name_747205",
                    "columns": {
                        "time_weighted_return": -0.046732301295604683,
                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.046732301295604683,
                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                        "value": 23132492.905107163
                    },
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Wealth Bucket A",
                            "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                            "columns": {
                                "time_weighted_return": -0.045960317420568164,
                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.045960317420568164,
                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                "value": 13264448.506587159
                            },
                            "children": [{
                                    "name": "Asset Class A",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": 0.000003434094574039648,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000003434094574039648,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 3337.99
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                        "entity_id": 10604454,
                                        "name": "HUDJ Trust",
                                        "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                        "columns": {
                                            "time_weighted_return": 0.000003434094574039648,
                                            "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000003434094574039648,
                                            "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                            "value": 3337.99
                                        },
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class B",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.025871339096964152,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.025871339096964152,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 1017004.7192636987
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                        "entity_id": 10604454,
                                        "name": "HUDG Trust",
                                        "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                        "columns": {
                                            "time_weighted_return": -0.025871339096964152,
                                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.025871339096964152,
                                            "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                            "value": 1017004.7192636987
                                        },
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class C",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.030370376329670656,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.030370376329670656,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 231142.67772000004
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                        "entity_id": 10604454,
                                        "name": "HKDJ Trust",
                                        "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                        "columns": {
                                            "time_weighted_return": -0.030370376329670656,
                                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.030370376329670656,
                                            "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                            "value": 231142.67772000004
                                        },
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class D",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.05382756475465478,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05382756475465478,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 9791282.570000006
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                        "entity_id": 10604454,
                                        "name": "HUDW Trust",
                                        "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                        "columns": {
                                            "time_weighted_return": -0.05382756475465478,
                                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05382756475465478,
                                            "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                            "value": 9791282.570000006
                                        },
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class E",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.01351630404081805,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.01351630404081805,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 2153366.6396034593
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                        "entity_id": 10604454,
                                        "name": "HJDJ Trust",
                                        "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                        "columns": {
                                            "time_weighted_return": -0.01351630404081805,
                                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.01351630404081805,
                                            "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                            "value": 2153366.6396034593
                                        },
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class F",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.002298190175237247,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.002298190175237247,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 68313.90999999999
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                        "entity_id": 10604454,
                                        "name": "HADJ Trust",
                                        "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                        "columns": {
                                            "time_weighted_return": -0.002298190175237247,
                                            "time_weighted_return_2": -0.002298190175237247,
                                            "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                            "value": 68313.90999999999
                                        },
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Wealth Bucket B",
                            "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577",
                            "columns": {
                                "time_weighted_return": -0.04769870075659244,
                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.04769870075659244,
                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                "value": 9868044.398519998
                            },
                            "children": [{
                                    "name": "Asset Class A",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": 0.000028632718065191298,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000028632718065191298,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 10234.94
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                            "entity_id": 10868778,
                                            "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": 0.0000282679297198829,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": 0.0000282679297198829,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 244.28
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10643052,
                                            "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": 0.000049373572795108345,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000049373572795108345,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 5081.08
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598341,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": 0.000006609603754315074,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000006609603754315074,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 1523.62
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598337,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": 0.000010999769004760296,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000010999769004760296,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 1828.9
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598334,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": 0.000006466673995619843,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": 0.000006466673995619843,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 1557.06
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class B",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.024645947842438676,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.024645947842438676,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 674052.31962
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                            "entity_id": 10868778,
                                            "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.043304004172576405,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.043304004172576405,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 52800.96
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10643052,
                                            "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.022408434778798836,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.022408434778798836,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 599594.11962
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598341,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.039799855483646174,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.039799855483646174,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 7219.08
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598337,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.039799855483646174,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.039799855483646174,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 7219.08
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598334,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.039799855483646174,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.039799855483646174,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 7219.08
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class C",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.03037038746301135,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.03037038746301135,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 114472.69744
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                            "entity_id": 10868778,
                                            "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.030370390035505124,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.030370390035505124,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 114472.68744000001
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10643052,
                                            "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": 0,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": 0,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 0.01
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class D",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.06604362523792162,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06604362523792162,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 5722529.229999997
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                            "entity_id": 10868778,
                                            "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.06154960593668424,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06154960593668424,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 1191838.9399999995
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10643052,
                                            "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.06750460387418267,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06750460387418267,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 4416618.520000002
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598341,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.05604507809250081,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05604507809250081,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 38190.33
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598337,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.05604507809250081,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05604507809250081,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 37940.72
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598334,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.05604507809250081,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05604507809250081,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 37940.72
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class E",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.017118805423322003,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.017118805423322003,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 3148495.0914600003
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                            "entity_id": 10868778,
                                            "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.015251157805867277,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.015251157805867277,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 800493.06146
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10643052,
                                            "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.01739609576880241,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.01739609576880241,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 2215511.2700000005
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598341,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.02085132265594647,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.02085132265594647,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 44031.21
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598337,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.02089393244695803,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.02089393244695803,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 44394.159999999996
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10598334,
                                            "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.020607507059866248,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.020607507059866248,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 44065.39000000001
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Asset Class F",
                                    "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287",
                                    "columns": {
                                        "time_weighted_return": -0.0014710489231547497,
                                        "time_weighted_return_2": -0.0014710489231547497,
                                        "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                        "value": 198260.12
                                    },
                                    "children": [{
                                            "entity_id": 10868778,
                                            "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.0014477244560456848,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.0014477244560456848,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 44612.33
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "entity_id": 10643052,
                                            "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia",
                                            "grouping": "legal_entity",
                                            "columns": {
                                                "time_weighted_return": -0.001477821083437858,
                                                "time_weighted_return_2": -0.001477821083437858,
                                                "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null,
                                                "value": 153647.78999999998
                                            },
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        "included": []
    }
}
```

**Notes on JSON Object extract**

1. `data` - data in here can be ignored, these are aggregated values for underlying children.
2. `meta` - `columns` – contains the column header values I want to use for each applicable `children` ‘column` key:pair values.
3. `groupings` - can be ignored.
4. `children` hierarchy – there are 4x levels of `children` which can be identified by their `name` as follows –

   - Family `name` (i.e., ‘Falconer Family’)
   - Wealth Bucket `name` (e.g., ‘Wealth Bucket A’)
   - Asset Class `name` (e.g., ‘Asset Class A’)
   - Fund `name` (e.g., ‘HUDJ Trust’)

**Target Output**
this is an extract of target `df` structure I am trying to achieve -

| **portfolio** | **name** | **entity_id** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** | **Current Quarter TWR (USD)** | **YTD TWR (USD)** | **TWR Audit Note** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Falconer Family | Falconer Family |  | 23132492.90510712 | -0.046732301295604683 | -0.046732301295604683 | None |
| Falconer Family | Wealth Bucket A |  | 13264448.506587146 | -0.045960317420568164 | -0.045960317420568164 | None |
| Falconer Family | Asset Class A |  | 3337.99 | 0.000003434094574039648 | 0.000003434094574039648 | None |
| Falconer Family | HUDJ Trust | 10604454 | 3337.99 | 0.000003434094574039648 | 0.000003434094574039648 | None |
| Falconer Family | Asset Class B |  | 1017004.7192636987 | -0.025871339096964152 | -0.025871339096964152 | None |
| Falconer Family | HUDG Trust | 10604454 | 1017004.7192636987 | -0.025871339096964152 | -0.025871339096964152 | None |
| Falconer Family | Asset Class C |  | 231142.67772000004 | -0.030370376329670656 | -0.030370376329670656 | None |
| Falconer Family | HKDJ Trust | 10604454 | 231142.67772000004 | -0.030370376329670656 | -0.030370376329670656 | None |
| Falconer Family | Asset Class D |  | 9791282.570000006 | -0.05382756475465478 | -0.05382756475465478 | None |
| Falconer Family | HUDW Trust | 10604454 | 9791282.570000006 | -0.05382756475465478 | -0.05382756475465478 | None |

**Notes on Target Output**

1. Portfolio header – for every row, I would like to map the top-level `children` `name` value [family name]. E.g., ‘Falconer Family.
2. Name header – this should simply be the `name` value from each respective `children`.
3. Entity ID – all 4th level `children` `entity_id` value should be mapped to this column.
4. Data columns – regardless of level, all `children` have identical `time_weighted_return`, `time-weighted_return2` and `value` columns which should be mapped respectively.
5. TWR Audit Note – these `children` `_custom_twr_audit_note_911318` values are currently blank, but will be utilized in the future.

**Current Output**
My main issue is that you can see that I have only been able to tap into the 1st [Family] and 2nd [Wealth Bucket] `children` level. This leaves me missing the 3rd [Asset Class] and 4th [Fund] -

|  | **portfolio** | **name** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** | **Current Quarter TWR (USD)** | **YTD TWR (USD)** | **TWR Audit Note)** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Falconer Family | Falconer Family | 2.313249e+07 | -0.046732 | -0.046732 | None |
| 1 | Falconer Family | Wealth Bucket A | 1.326445e+07 | -0.045960 | -0.045960 | None |
| 2 | Falconer Family | Wealth Bucket B | 9.868044e+06 | -0.047699 | -0.047699 | None |

**Current code**
This is a function which gets me the correct `df` formatting, however my main issue is that I haven't been able to find a solution to returning all children, but rather only the top-level -

```
# Function to read API response / JSON Object
def response_writer():
    with open('api_response_2022-02-13.json') as f:
        api_response = json.load(f)
        return api_response

# Function to unpack JSON response into pandas dataframe.
def unpack_response():
    while True:
        try:
            api_response = response_writer()
            portfolio_views_children = api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children']
            portfolios = []
            for portfolio in portfolio_views_children:
                entity_columns = []
                # include portfolio itself within an iterable so the total is the header
                for entity in itertools.chain([portfolio], portfolio["children"]):
                    entity_data = entity["columns"].copy()  # don't mutate original response
                    entity_data["portfolio"] = portfolio["name"]   # from outer
                    entity_data["name"]      = entity["name"]
                    entity_columns.append(entity_data)

                df = pd.DataFrame(entity_columns)
                portfolios.append(df)

            # combine dataframes
            df = pd.concat(portfolios)
            # reorder and rename
            column_ordering = {"portfolio": "portfolio", "name": "name"}
            column_ordering.update({c["key"]: c["display_name"] for c in api_response["meta"]["columns"]})
            df = df[column_ordering.keys()]   # beware: un-named cols will be dropped
            df = df.rename(columns=column_ordering)
            break
        except KeyError:
            print("-----------------------------------\n","API TIMEOUT ERROR: TRY AGAIN...", "\n-----------------------------------\n")
    return df
unpack_response()
```

**Help**
In short, I am looking for some advice on how I can tap into the remaining `children` by enhancing the existing code. Whilst I have taken much time to fully explain my problem, please ask if anything isn't clear. Please note that the JSON may have multiple families, so the solution / advice offered must observe this

Comment: Question: Does the order of the rows matter?

Comment: No - no preference on ordeirng

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`jsonpath-ng`](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng) can parse even such a nested json object very easily. You can install this convenient library by the following command:

```sh
pip install --upgrade jsonpath-ng
```

### Code:

```py
import json
import jsonpath_ng as jp
import pandas as pd

def unpack_response(r):
    # Create a dataframe from extracted data
    expr = jp.parse('$..children.[*]')
    data = [{'full_path': str(m.full_path), **m.value} for m in expr.find(r)]
    df = pd.json_normalize(data).sort_values('full_path', ignore_index=True)

    # Append a portfolio column
    df['portfolio'] = df.loc[df.full_path.str.contains(r'total\.children\.\[\d+]$'), 'name']
    df['portfolio'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

    # Deal with columns
    trans = {'columns.' + c['key']: c['display_name'] for c in r['meta']['columns']}
    cols = ['full_path', 'portfolio', 'name', 'entity_id', 'Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)', 'Current Quarter TWR (USD)', 'YTD TWR (USD)', 'TWR Audit Note']
    df = df.rename(columns=trans)[cols]

    return df

# Load the sample data from file
# with open('api_response_2022-02-13.json', 'r') as f:
#     api_response = json.load(f)

# Load the sample data from string
api_response = json.loads('{"meta": {"columns": [{"key": "value", "display_name": "Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)", "output_type": "Number", "currency": "USD"}, {"key": "time_weighted_return", "display_name": "Current Quarter TWR (USD)", "output_type": "Percent", "currency": "USD"}, {"key": "time_weighted_return_2", "display_name": "YTD TWR (USD)", "output_type": "Percent", "currency": "USD"}, {"key": "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328", "display_name": "TWR Audit Note", "output_type": "Word"}], "groupings": [{"key": "_custom_name_747205", "display_name": "* Reporting Client Name"}, {"key": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577", "display_name": "NEW Entity Group"}, {"key": "_custom_level_2_624287", "display_name": "* Level 2"}, {"key": "legal_entity", "display_name": "Legal Entity"}]}, "data": {"type": "portfolio_views", "attributes": {"total": {"name": "Total", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.046732301295604683, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.046732301295604683, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 23132492.905107163}, "children": [{"name": "Falconer Family", "grouping": "_custom_name_747205", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.046732301295604683, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.046732301295604683, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 23132492.905107163}, "children": [{"name": "Wealth Bucket A", "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.045960317420568164, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.045960317420568164, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 13264448.506587159}, "children": [{"name": "Asset Class A", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 3.434094574039648e-06, "time_weighted_return_2": 3.434094574039648e-06, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 3337.99}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10604454, "name": "HUDJ Trust", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 3.434094574039648e-06, "time_weighted_return_2": 3.434094574039648e-06, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 3337.99}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class B", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.025871339096964152, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.025871339096964152, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 1017004.7192636987}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10604454, "name": "HUDG Trust", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.025871339096964152, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.025871339096964152, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 1017004.7192636987}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class C", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.030370376329670656, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.030370376329670656, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 231142.67772000004}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10604454, "name": "HKDJ Trust", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.030370376329670656, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.030370376329670656, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 231142.67772000004}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class D", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.05382756475465478, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05382756475465478, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 9791282.570000006}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10604454, "name": "HUDW Trust", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.05382756475465478, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05382756475465478, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 9791282.570000006}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class E", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.01351630404081805, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.01351630404081805, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 2153366.6396034593}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10604454, "name": "HJDJ Trust", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.01351630404081805, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.01351630404081805, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 2153366.6396034593}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class F", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.002298190175237247, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.002298190175237247, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 68313.90999999999}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10604454, "name": "HADJ Trust", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.002298190175237247, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.002298190175237247, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 68313.90999999999}, "children": []}]}]}, {"name": "Wealth Bucket B", "grouping": "_custom_new_entity_group_453577", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.04769870075659244, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.04769870075659244, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 9868044.398519998}, "children": [{"name": "Asset Class A", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 2.8632718065191298e-05, "time_weighted_return_2": 2.8632718065191298e-05, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 10234.94}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10868778, "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 2.82679297198829e-05, "time_weighted_return_2": 2.82679297198829e-05, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 244.28}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10643052, "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 4.9373572795108345e-05, "time_weighted_return_2": 4.9373572795108345e-05, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 5081.08}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598341, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 6.609603754315074e-06, "time_weighted_return_2": 6.609603754315074e-06, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 1523.62}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598337, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 1.0999769004760296e-05, "time_weighted_return_2": 1.0999769004760296e-05, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 1828.9}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598334, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 6.466673995619843e-06, "time_weighted_return_2": 6.466673995619843e-06, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 1557.06}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class B", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.024645947842438676, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.024645947842438676, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 674052.31962}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10868778, "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.043304004172576405, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.043304004172576405, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 52800.96}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10643052, "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.022408434778798836, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.022408434778798836, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 599594.11962}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598341, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.039799855483646174, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.039799855483646174, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 7219.08}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598337, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.039799855483646174, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.039799855483646174, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 7219.08}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598334, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.039799855483646174, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.039799855483646174, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 7219.08}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class C", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.03037038746301135, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.03037038746301135, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 114472.69744}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10868778, "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.030370390035505124, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.030370390035505124, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 114472.68744000001}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10643052, "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": 0, "time_weighted_return_2": 0, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 0.01}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class D", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.06604362523792162, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06604362523792162, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 5722529.229999997}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10868778, "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.06154960593668424, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06154960593668424, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 1191838.9399999995}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10643052, "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.06750460387418267, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.06750460387418267, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 4416618.520000002}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598341, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.05604507809250081, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05604507809250081, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 38190.33}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598337, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.05604507809250081, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05604507809250081, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 37940.72}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598334, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.05604507809250081, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.05604507809250081, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 37940.72}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class E", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.017118805423322003, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.017118805423322003, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 3148495.0914600003}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10868778, "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.015251157805867277, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.015251157805867277, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 800493.06146}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10643052, "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.01739609576880241, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.01739609576880241, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 2215511.2700000005}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598341, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Shirley", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.02085132265594647, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.02085132265594647, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 44031.21}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598337, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Hannah", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.02089393244695803, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.02089393244695803, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 44394.159999999996}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10598334, "name": "Cht 11th Tr HBO Lau", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.020607507059866248, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.020607507059866248, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 44065.39000000001}, "children": []}]}, {"name": "Asset Class F", "grouping": "_custom_level_2_624287", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.0014710489231547497, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.0014710489231547497, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 198260.12}, "children": [{"entity_id": 10868778, "name": "2012 Desc Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.0014477244560456848, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.0014477244560456848, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 44612.33}, "children": []}, {"entity_id": 10643052, "name": "2013 Irrev Tr HBO Thalia", "grouping": "legal_entity", "columns": {"time_weighted_return": -0.001477821083437858, "time_weighted_return_2": -0.001477821083437858, "_custom_twr_audit_note_911328": null, "value": 153647.78999999998}, "children": []}]}]}]}]}}, "included": []}}')

df = unpack_response(api_response)
```

### Explanation:

Firstly, you can confirm the expected output by the following command:

```py
print(df.iloc[:5:,1:])
```

| portfolio | name | entity_id | Adjusted Value (No Div, USD) | Current Quarter TWR (USD) | YTD TWR (USD) | TWR Audit Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Falconer Family | Falconer Family | nan | 2.31325e+07 | -0.0467323 | -0.0467323 |  |
| Falconer Family | Wealth Bucket A | nan | 1.32644e+07 | -0.0459603 | -0.0459603 |  |
| Falconer Family | Asset Class A | nan | 3337.99 | 3.43409e-06 | 3.43409e-06 |  |
| Falconer Family | HUDJ Trust | 1.06045e+07 | 3337.99 | 3.43409e-06 | 3.43409e-06 |  |
| Falconer Family | Asset Class B | nan | 1.017e+06 | -0.0258713 | -0.0258713 |  |

Subsequently, you can see one of the wonderful features in `jsonpath-ng` by the following command:

```py
print(df.iloc[:10,:3])
```

| full_path | portfolio | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0] | Falconer Family | Falconer Family |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0] | Falconer Family | Wealth Bucket A |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Falconer Family | Asset Class A |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Falconer Family | HUDJ Trust |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1] | Falconer Family | Asset Class B |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Falconer Family | HUDG Trust |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[2] | Falconer Family | Asset Class C |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[2].children.[0] | Falconer Family | HKDJ Trust |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[3] | Falconer Family | Asset Class D |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[3].children.[0] | Falconer Family | HUDW Trust |

Thanks to the `full_path` column, you can grasp the nesting level of the extracted data in each row instantaneously. Actually, I appended the correct `portfolio` values by using these paths.

In terms of the code, the key point is the following line:

```py
expr = jp.parse('$..children.[*]')
```

By the above expression, you can search the `children` attributes at any level of the json object. [README.rst](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/blob/master/README.rst) tells you what each syntax stands for.

| Syntax | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `$` | The root object |
| `jsonpath1 .. jsonpath2` | All nodes matched by jsonpath2 that descend from any node matching jsonpath1 |
| `[*]` | any array index |

### Speed:

I compared the speed between the above method with `jsonpath-ng` and a nested-for-loop method shown below.

##### # Comparison:

| Method | Duration | Speed ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `jsonpath-ng` | 9.72 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) | 5.7 (faster) |
| Nested-for-loop | 55.4 ms ± 7.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) | 1 |

##### # Code of the nested-for-loop method:

```py
def unpack_response(r):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for _, r1 in pd.json_normalize(r, ['data', 'attributes', 'total', 'children']).iterrows(): 
        r1['portfolio'] = r1['name']
        df = df.append(r1)
        for _, r2 in pd.json_normalize(r1.children).iterrows(): 
            df = df.append(r2)
            for _, r3 in pd.json_normalize(r2.children).iterrows(): 
                df = df.append(r3).append(pd.json_normalize(r3.children))
    df['portfolio'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    trans = {'columns.' + c['key']: c['display_name'] for c in r['meta']['columns']}
    cols = ['portfolio', 'name', 'entity_id', 'Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)', 'Current Quarter TWR (USD)', 'YTD TWR (USD)', 'TWR Audit Note']
    df = df.rename(columns=trans)[cols].reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
```

Comment: triple `for` loop with `iterrows` is completely unnecessary

Comment: @KingOtto, You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll try to come up with another version.

Comment: @William, I found a nice library. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this gets you pretty close; might just need to adjust the various `name` columns and drop the extra data (I kept the `grouping` column).

The main idea is to recursively use [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for all availalable `children` levels.

**EDIT:** Put everything into a single function and added section to collapse the `name` columns like the expected output.

```
def process_json(api_response): 
    
    def get_column_values(df):    
        return pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.pop('columns')).set_axis(df.index)], axis=1)
    
    def expand_children(df):
        if len(df.index) > 1:
            df['children'] = df['children'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: None if len(x) == 0 else x)
        df_children = df.pop('children').dropna().explode()
        if len(df_children.index) == 0: # return df if no children to append
            return df.index.names, df
        df_children = pd.json_normalize(df_children, max_level=0).set_axis(df_children.index).set_index('name', append=True)
        df_children = get_column_values(df_children)
        idx_names = list(df_children.index.names)
        idx_names[-1] = idx_names[-1] + '_' + str(len(idx_names))
        df[idx_names[-1]] = None
        return idx_names, pd.concat([df.set_index(idx_names[-1], append=True), df_children], axis=0)    
    
    columns_dict = pd.DataFrame(api_response['meta']['columns']).set_index('key').to_dict(orient='index') # save column definitions
    df = pd.DataFrame(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children']).set_index('name') # get initial dataframe     
    df = get_column_values(df) # get columns for initial level
    
    # expand children
    while 'children' in df.columns:
        idx_names, df = expand_children(df)
    
    # reorder/replace column headers and sort index
    df = (df.loc[:, [x for x in df.columns if x not in columns_dict.keys()] + list(columns_dict.keys())]
          .rename(columns={k:v['display_name'] for k,v in columns_dict.items()})
          .sort_index(na_position='first').reset_index())
    
    #collapse "name" columns (careful of potential duplicate rows)  
    for col in idx_names[::-1]:
            df[idx_names[-1]] = df[idx_names[-1]].fillna(df[col])
    df = df.rename(columns={'name': 'portfolio', idx_names[-1]: 'name'}).drop(columns=idx_names[1:-1])      
    
    return df
```

Since the other answer uses `iterrows`, which usually isn't advised, figured a quick time compare was worthwhile.

```
process_json(api_response)
54.2 ms ± 7.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

unpack_response(api_response) # iterrows
84.3 ms ± 9.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: No, you don't want to collapse the `name` columns. They are not to be mapped, but actually does contain different hierarchical information that is requried ('Wealth Bucket A/B' are on level 1, while 'HUDW Trust' is on level 3) -- this will take additional intelligence to decide which name should go into the final output column

Comment: I agree, which why I was hesitant to collapse them at first and included a warning in my code comment. However, the question's expected output does display them in such a manner, so I opted to include that part of the code. Those couple of lines can easily be removed from the bottom of the function though.

Comment: Fully agree... the question is unclear, here. Somehow in the output, some collapsing has taken place, but the "magic" behind that collapse is elusive, as some of the data from level_1 and some from level_3 has been included.. That's why in my answer I have decided to keep them all. More work will be needed to define some form of "final name"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have 3 layers of 'nested' children within one json. You want to laod them all into `pandas` and un-nest them (`explode` them) in `pandas`, not manually in an outer `for` loop.

Challenge: while exploding, every child in turn has a field called `name`, which already exists in the parent child. We thus need to rename those while we do the successive explosions (as you did in your original question, e.g., 'portfolio' is actually called 'name' in the json). Eventually all the other values saved in the `columns` information can be `unpack`ed.

Full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# get the json file
json_dict = json.load(open('api_response_2022-02-13.json'))
    

# create a (nested) df out of it, and rename the 'top-level' name field to 'portfolio'
packed_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])\
            .rename(columns={'name': 'portfolio'})

# expand the level-1 'children' (and call their 'name' field 'grand-parent')
unpacked_df = packed_df.groupby('portfolio')['children']\
              .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0])).reset_index()\
              .rename(columns={'name': 'grand_parent_name'})

# expand the level-2 'children' (and call their 'name' field 'parent')
unpacked_df = unpacked_df.groupby(['portfolio', 'grand_parent_name'])['children']\
              .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0])).reset_index()\
              .rename(columns={'name': 'parent_name'})

# expand the level-3 'children' (and keep their name as is)
unpacked_df = unpacked_df.groupby(['portfolio', 'grand_parent_name', 'parent_name'])['children']\
              .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0])).reset_index()

# expand the column field info from 'dict' to multiple columns
unpacked_df = pd.concat([unpacked_df.drop('columns', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(unpacked_df['columns'].tolist())], axis=1)
```

Of course, you can put the 3 recursive un-packing steps into a separate function, but kept them separate here for sake of clarity (you are actually un-packing different hierarchies of 'children', and need to take care of each 'name' separately)

In the end, you have all the columns from all the 3 hierarchical levels (all the json in one df) - rename them, delete some of them, as you please. For your final output, your screenshot already mixes the different `name` levels ("Wealth Bucket A/B" is not on same level as "HUDW/HADJ Trust")